# How to set "status" in queue

Tags: javascript, typescript, queue, task-queue, bull-queue

I have a function which add me to queue a job like this:

```
    async addJob(someParameters: SomeParameters): Promise<void> {
        await this.saveToDb(someParameters);
        try {
            await this.jobQueue.add('job', {
                someParameters
            })
        } catch (error) {
        }
    }
```

but before adding to queue I save my data in database. My entity have a enum field "Status" with some parameters.

In my `job.process.ts` i have my queue processor:

```
    @Process('job')
    async runJob(job: Job<{param: SomeParameters}>): Promise<any> {
        try {
              await this.launchMyFunction(param);
            }
        } 
    }
```

and another function to monitoring a job in the queue:

```
@OnQueueCompleted()
    async onCompleted(job: Job): Promise<void> {
        await this.updateJobStatus(here must be ID from DB); //HERE IS PROBLEM
    }
```

and right now i have a problem, how to get and ID from my databse of the current job in queue and set a status to this record in database?

Comment: Have you tried job id?

Answer (score 0):

You can use job id, and get it in job parameter in process.